# rails and ruby gems up-to-date version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my gem gem file as you can see I use outdated version of rails and may be ruby and may be something else. This happened because I Followed Michel's Hart tutorial and took this gems from there.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'ffaker'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.9'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'blogo'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'

end


gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'heroku-deflater'
end
```

> Hello,
>
> On Feb 24, 2016, Ruby 2.0.0 security maintenance will reach its
>   end-of-life. When this happens, Ruby 2.0.0 will no longer receive
>   security updates. We recommend that you upgrade your app to a
>   supported Ruby version, e.g. 2.2.4, to ensure that your application is
>   running in a secure environment.

So which version of the ruby and rails do you suggest to put into my gemfile?

Comment: You can check google to find the latest stable versions. It's 2.3 for ruby and 4.2 for rails

Comment: thanks,  `gem 'rails', '4.2.0'` and `ruby '2.3.0'` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the most current stable rails and ruby versions. 
at this point that would be `ruby '2.3'` and  `rails '4.2'`

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing most current ruby supported on heroku is 2.3.0. 
To run rails on 2.3 without warnings about some cyclic dependencies you need rails 4.2+, but note that some things changed from 4.0 to 4.2 and you may have to do a migration, see [guide on that](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)